# jquery getJSON callback issues

Tags: jquery

I have this function that runs when a city select box changes upon user selecting a city:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadParishesByCity(city_id,loadDists) {
    alert('here'); // Never gets here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#city").change(function(e,loadDists) {
        var loadDists = loadDists || false;                    
        var clickedID = $(this).val();
        var city_id = clickedID.split("_")[0];

        $.getJSON("/system.cfc?method=setGeo&returnformat=json",{"geoType":"city","geoValue":city_id},function(res,code){
            loadParishesByCity(city_id,loadDists); //this seems to not run
        });         
    });
});
</script>
```

The getJSON function runs and returns data as expected, but the callback function loadParishesByCity doesn't seem to run.

I admit to having a gap in my understanding when it comes to callback functions and race conditions so any help much appreciated.

Comment: check your console... i guess you have an error .... :)

Comment: Nearly right. I feel like an idiot. I had some code which stopped processing after running the getJSON function.

Comment: Make yours an answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

few thinks to look for

1) make sure you have no other error that is blocking the script ... check you developer's tool console if you have any errors.... your above code (jquery getJSON callback issues)  looks fine to me (no syntax error as far as i know).

2) make sure the path is correct. anyways if path is incorrect the error should be displayed in the console..

> press F12 for developer tools and click on console tab